# SOSL Query on Product does not search the standard Family field

Tags: sosl, product

I am executing the following query:

```
FIND {LANDWAGEN} IN ALL Fields RETURNING Product2(ProductCode ORDER BY ProductCode)
```

I know there are products with this value in the Family field, but 0 rows are returned. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklist fields are not search indexed. Use SOQL instead. See [Searchable Fields by Object in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5) and [Searchable Fields by Object in Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_cex.htm&type=5).

Comment: I must use SOSL, because I want the search term (entered by users) to search in all product fields. I guess I have to create a custom field.